# How can I access the "arrow" button click event on Material UI data grid?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui

In the documentation of [Material UI Data Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/events/) it has this code snippet (I've made a couple slight changes like importing DataGrid instead of DataGridPro, etc.):

```
import { DataGrid, useGridApiRef } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';

export default function PageChange() {
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState('');
  const data = {'dummy-data-for-now': ''};

  React.useEffect(() => {
    /* ---- Theoretically I would replace columnResize with 'pageChange' ---- */
    return apiRef.current.subscribeEvent('columnResize', (params) => {
      setMessage(
        `Column ${params.colDef.headerName} resized to ${params.computedWidth}px.`,
      );
    });
  }, [apiRef]);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <div style={{ height: 180, width: '100%' }}>
        <DataGrid apiRef={apiRef} {...data} />
      </div>
      {message && (
        <Alert severity="info" style={{ marginTop: 8 }}>
          {message}
        </Alert>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am implementing API pagination of 10 results at a time. I would like to be able to make a new API call for the next (or previous) 10 results when I click the arrow buttons.

The documentation refers to `pageChange` as an event option, but when I use the code snippet, I don't know how to utilize it. I would really appreciate any insight anyone might have on how to handle this situation.

[This is a picture of the data grid button, for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyZ3o.png)

Comment: <DataGrid
  pageChange ={(params, event) => {
    console.log(params, event);
}}
/>

Have you tried this? Log the parameters and see what they contain

Comment: On this page there is an example of "Server-Side Pagination", it is not what you need? https://material-ui.com/ru/components/data-grid/pagination/

Comment: Thank you @MaxAlex! This helped me figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

@MaxAlex, thank you for the tip! This sent me on the right path and I finally got it working with server-side pagination. [Resource](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/pagination/)

The key for me was to realize that on the onPageChange property within the DataGrid: `onPageChange={(newPage) => handlePageChange(newPage)}`, "newPage" was an object with the page number. I didn't need to specifically access the forward and backward arrows, but instead, just manage "newPage" in my handlePageChange function.